# For which $n$, is $\Bbb{Z}_n \cong H \oplus (\Bbb{Z}_n/H) $ is true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

> Give a characterization of all positive integers $n$ for which $$\Bbb{Z}_n \cong H \oplus (\Bbb{Z}_n/H) $$ for every subgroup $H$ of $\Bbb{Z}_n$.

For $n$ is prime ,then $\Bbb{Z}_n $ has only two improper subgroups. So the conclusion is true. What about other $n$'s?

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: From wikipedia :  If the $n_i$ are pairwise coprime, the map
$$x \;\text{mod}\;n \rightarrow (x \;\text{mod}\;n_1,x\; \text{mod}\;n_2,....,x\; \text{mod}\;n_k)$$
defines a ring isomorphism 
$$ \Bbb{Z}_n \simeq \Bbb{Z}_{n_1} \times \Bbb{Z}_{n_2} \times ..... \Bbb{Z}_{n_k}$$ 
between the ring of integers modulo n and the direct product of the rings of integers modulo the $n_i$.

Comment: Applying that to the additive group answers the question, once you realize that being divisible by any square of a prime will make the property fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few facts that need to be known to finish this exercise:

(1) a subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

This is an easy exercise, either by lifting the subgroup to $\mathbb{Z}$ or by considering a given generator $g$ of the big group and the minimal power $n$ such that $g^n \in H$

(2) A quotient of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Again, this is an easy exercise: the image of a generator under the quotient map is a generator of the quotient group.

(3) The chinese remainder theorem: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic (hence of order $mn$) if and only if $m\land n = 1$.

This is a classical result.

(4) For any $d\mid n$, there is a (unique- but it's not necessary for the remainder of the proof) subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ of order $d$.

Put $H:=\langle \frac{n}{d}\rangle$.

With these in mind, if $n$ is such that for all $H\leq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\simeq H\oplus ((\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/H)$; then this means, by (1),(2) and (3), that for all subgroups $H$ of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, $|H|$ and $\frac{n}{|H|}$ are coprime, and by (1),(2) and (3), this condition is also sufficient.

By (4) and Lagrange's theorem, this is equivalent to saying that for all $d\mid n$, $d\land \frac{n}{d} =1$.

If $n=p_1...p_k$ with $p_i$'s distinct primes, then clearly this is the case. If $p^2\mid n$, $p$ prime then $p\mid p \land \frac{n}{p}$, and so this isn't the case.

In conclusion, this is true of $n$ if and only if $n$ is a product of distinct primes (aka $n$ is squarefree)